# Traverse Tree in Java

Tags: java

I have a problem with traversing a tree and to have an output as the following.

The image if the tree is like this. [http://www.java-forums.org/attachments/advanced-java/3355d1332821031t-traversing-binary-tree-root-each-branch-binarytree.png][1]

Output:

1. A, A1, A2, B1, B2
2. A, A1, B1, A2, B2
3. A, A1, B1, B2, A2
4. A, B1, A1, A2, B2
5. A, B1, A1, B2, A2
6. A, B1, B2, A1, A2

I understand that this is very similar to the preorder traversal, but preorder does not output the parent nodes another time when the node splits into a left and right node. Any suggestions?

Here is my code but I am stuck at the printing out.

```
public class BinaryTreeTest {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here

    int countA = 0;
    int countB = 0;
    ArrayList listA = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList listB = new ArrayList();
    listA.add("A1");
    listA.add("A2");
    listA.add("A3");
    listB.add("B1");
    listB.add("B2");
    listB.add("B3");
    //listB.add("B1");
    Node root = new Node("START");
    constructTree(root, countA, countB, listA, listB);

    //printInOrder(root);
    //printFromRoot(root);



}


public static class Node{
    private Node left;
    private Node right;
    private String value;
    public Node(String value){
        this.value = value;
    }
}

public static void constructTree(Node node, int countA, int countB, ArrayList listA, ArrayList listB){
    if(countA < listA.size()){
        if(node.left == null){
            System.out.println("There is no left node. CountA is " + countA);
            System.out.println("Created new node with value: " + listA.get(countA).toString() + " with parent, "
                    + node.value);
            System.out.println();
            node.left = new Node(listA.get(countA).toString());  
            constructTree(node.left, countA+1, countB, listA, listB);    
        }else{
            System.out.println("There is a left node. CountA + 1 is " + countA+1);
            constructTree(node.left, countA+1, countB, listA, listB);    
        }
    }
    if(countB < listB.size()){
        if(node.right == null){
            System.out.println("There is no right node. CountB is " + countB);
            System.out.println("Created new node with value: " + listB.get(countB).toString() + " with parent, "
                    + node.value);
            System.out.println();
            node.right = new Node(listB.get(countB).toString());
            constructTree(node.right, countA, countB+1, listA, listB); 
        }else{
            System.out.println("There is a right node. CountB + 1 is " + countB+1);
            constructTree(node.right, countA, countB+1, listA, listB);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And where is the most important thing called Code?

Comment: What is the problem exactly ? From what you're showing what you'd need to do is get the leftmost node on each move. You'd also need to mark off nodes as completed.

Answer (score 1):

what you want to do is traversing the tree with a depth-first algorithme.

You will find a lot of example over the internet. Depending on how you make your tree. You can make a recursive algo passing each child from left to right or using a visitor pattern if you got a tree of object already loaded.

First, take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#Depth-first